# Get row data from jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a small question about jquery datatable. What I need is, to select a row and get data in that row. There are a lot of web links has below code to get selected row data.

```
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;

    } );
```

It should assign variable "id" to that table row "id" value. But when I try above code, at least it is not trigger the click event. Then i try below code.

```
        $('#example').on('click', 'tbody','tr', function () {
            var id = this.id;

        } );
```

It is trigger the click event, but not return row data. It is return tbody data. How to get row data and why my code doest work as per the [web link](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/select_rows.html).

> EDIT

Below code is worked for me....

```
        $('#example').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
            var id = this.id;

        } );
```

Comment: You can't have two selector parameters

Comment: Perhaps you meant `.on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {`

Comment: Thanks Phiter... I added working code in EDIT section.