# JQuery Datatable get row data by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a small problem about jquery datatable. I'm trying to make table were when I click on one row I need to get data from that row. I found this like exemple but did not worked for me:

```
var table = $('#table1').DataTable();
 
$('#myTable').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    var id = table.row( this ).id();
 
    alert( 'Clicked row id '+id );
} );
```

Whei I tryied this the `id` was always undefined.

```
var table = $('#table1').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row(this).data();
        alert('You clicked on ' + data[0] + '\'s row');
    });
});
```

Same thing when I trtied this. I also I have seen this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264581/get-row-data-from-jquery-datatable) that didn't help me.

This is my tabel in HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cgnome</th>
                <th>Ani</th>
                <th>Data</th>
                <th>Paese</th>
                    ....
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

And this is what I tryied in javascript :

```
    var oTable1;
    var id;
    $('#table1').on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
        id = this.id; // is always `id = ""`
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    LoadMissioniOptimizer();
});

function LoadMissioniOptimizer() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/My/GetAppSettingFromKey?key=MissioniOptimizer",
        ASYNC: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            var apiUrl = data;
            oTable1 =
                $('#table1').DataTable({
                    ajax: '/api/staff',
                    rowId: 'staffId',
                    scrollY: '50vh',
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging: false,
                    scrollX: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    serverSide: false,
                    processing: true,
                    searching: true,
                    ordering: true,
                    orderMulti: false,
                    colReorder: true,
                    paging: true,
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "Nome", responsivePriority: 1, "searchable": true },
                        { "data": "Cognome", responsivePriority: 2, "searchable": true },
                        { "data": "Ani", responsivePriority: 3, "searchable": true },
                        { "data": "Data", responsivePriority: 4, "searchable": true },
                        { "data": "Paese", responsivePriority: 5, "searchable": true },
                                     .......
                        ],
                    columnDefs: [
                        {
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                            targets: 0
                        },
                        {
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                            targets: 1
                        },
                        {
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                            targets: 2
                        },
                        {
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                            targets: 3
                        },
                        {
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                            targets: 4
                        },
                    ]
                });
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: There is no `tbody` in your HTML, but you use `'tbody tr'` in your click function.

Comment: Ti consiglio non solo di ripassare i selettori ma anche di considerare qualcosa di un po' più moderno, le table fatte con jquery sono da anni 90. Se poi lo fai per studio mi scuso.

Comment: Even without tbout i get allways id = undefined

Comment: Cosa posso usare di piu moderno?

Comment: Ci sono diversi framework abbastanza conosciuti (per esempio il trio React-Vue-Angular), che hanno come "accompagnamento" diverse librerie piuttosto fiche. Ma mi rendo conto che per iniziare a studiare non sono il massimo. In alternativa ci sarebbe Boostrap o Foundation... Ma di nuovo ripeto: se stai studiando le basi non è saggio sviare. Ho detto di ripassare i selettori perché nello snippet leggo "#example tbody", ma nell'HTML che hai aggiunto non mi sembra di vedere alcun id example.

Comment: Grazie. Ho lasciato "#example tbody" perche io in realta non ho tbody in HTML.

Comment: Pur non avendo un tbody l'evento click parte lo stesso?

Comment: This worked for me:  $('#table name ').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = table.row(this).id();  I added **rowId: 'column name '** when I name ajax call

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about datatables but here is simple JS to get all tr row data into array.

Just change `innerHTML` into what you actually need.

```js
var data = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll('tr')].forEach(tr => {
  tr.addEventListener('click', event => {
    data = [];
    [...tr.children].forEach(td => {
      data.push(td.innerHTML);
    })
    console.clear();
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Cgnome</th>
        <th>Ani</th>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Paese</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome2</th>
        <th>Cgnome2</th>
        <th>Ani2</th>
        <th>Data2</th>
        <th>Paese2</th>
      </tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
        <th>data1 row1</th>
        <th>data2 row1</th>
        <th>data3 row1</th>
        <th>data4 row1</th>
        <th>data5 row1</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>data1 row2</th>
        <th>data2 row2</th>
        <th>data3 row2</th>
        <th>data4 row2</th>
        <th>data5 row2</th>
      </tr>  
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue with adding row call back function:

**Easy and effective way:**

Add this function on **DataTable definition**:

```
        rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
            $(row).unbind('click');
            $(row).bind('click', () => {
              yourClickFunction(data);
            });
        }
```

**Like this:**

```
                    .
                    .
                    .


         columnDefs: [
                {
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                    targets: 0
                },
                {
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                    targets: 1
                },
                {
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                    targets: 2
                },
                {
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                    targets: 3
                },
                {
                    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text(),
                    targets: 4
                },
            ],
            rowCallback: function(row, data, index) {
            $(row).unbind('click');
            $(row).bind('click', () => {
              yourClickFunction(data);
            });
        }
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

This function in your **Js file**, what it will show you data.

```
        function yourClickFunction(rowData) {
          console.log("YourClickData:", rowData);
        }
```

DataTable Official site help [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback)